# Автогенерация кода

Tags: lisp, метапрограммирование, макросы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, на каком из языков программирования можно написать программу, которая способна создать другую программу, а так же полностью изменить себя?

Какие способы есть для этого, макросы, метапрограммирование? Чем тогда отличаются макросы ассемблера от макросов Lisp?

Comment: Да на любом языке возможно это реализовать , другой вопрос сколько на это усилий потребуется.

Comment: Себя изменить может так (для юниксовых систем): программа генерирует исполняемый файл (можно даже на скриптовом языке) и далее системным вызовом execve запускает его. В результате полностью изменяется образ процесса. Минус - меняется все, в том числе куча и стек.

Comment: Кстати, можно даже на shell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Подскажите пожалуйста на каком из языков программирования можно написать программу которая способна создать другую программу, а так же полностью изменить себя?

Для использования возможностей метапрограммирования достаточно наличия в языке `eval`. Возможность построить и выполнить произвольный код который будет влиять на текущий контекст — мощное средство с помощью которого можно писать программы, пишущие программы.

Чтобы "изменять себя" достаточно переопределять существующий код в рантайме. Это можно сделать много где:  Smalltalk, Python, Ruby, JavaScript.

Иногда много средств для изменения кода на лету доступно из без `eval`, когда среда поддерживает рефлексию. (Smalltalk)

> Какие способы есть для этого, макросы, метапрограммирование? Чем тогда отличаются макросы ассемблера от макросов Lisp?

Макросы Lisp — это просто удобное средство для преобразования AST перед компиляцией ничего больше. Разница в том, что макросы asm и C-предпроцессора оперируют кусками текста. Макросы Lisp оперируют выражениями. Кроме того, макросы в Lisp -- полноценные программы, и с помощью них можно строить весьма сложные выражения.

**UPD**:

`eval` — это процедура которая принимает исходный код в виде данных (просто строку или AST) и выполняет его.

Например в JavaScript можно написать так:

```
eval("function some_func() { return 1; }")
```

Здесь код передан как простой текст, но после выполнения будет объявлена функция `some_func` в текущем контексте, и мы сможем ею оперировать.

```
some_func()   // вернёт 1
```

Так как передаётся простой текст, то мы можем его преобразовывать любыми способами, и в итоге выполнить произвольный код в рантайме.

AST — abstract syntax tree, такая структура данных (дерево) в которую преобразуется исходный код какого-либо языка после парсинга. После того как получено AST обычно над ним производят ряд преобразований (оптимизаций), а потом компилируют в машинный код.

В случае Lisp из-за простоты синтаксиса AST будет обычный линейный список, например код:

```
(some-construction (for i 0) ((i) exit))
```

В виде списка (AST) будет почти так же:

```
(list 'some-construcion
      (list 'for 'i 0)
      (list (list 'i) 'exit))
;; Или достаточно закавычить, чтобы получить тот же список
'(some-construction (for i 0) ((i) exit))
```

Макросы — просто программы которые оперируют этой структурой данных, уже после того как код был прочтён, но ещё не оптимизирован и не скомпилирован. Они позволяют легко встраивать новые конструкции в язык, которые потом преобразуются в какие-то стандартные конструкции.

Полезно взглянуть на язык Nemerle, который также поддерживает макросы, но не является лиспоподобным.

Comment: А в краце можете пожалуйста пояснить что такое eval и AST? в гугле чушь какая то, не могу найти. Спасибо кстати за развернутый ответ.

Comment: Раз уж упомянули добавление кода в рантайме, не могу не вспомнить Objective-C.

Comment: updated post

Answer (score 2):

Почти у всех уже установлен .NET Framework, в котором есть компилятор C#. Можно написать программу, которая генерирует код C# и передаёт его компилятору.

Добавлено:
Ещё один вариант изучаю:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned char data[]={0xb8, 0x9a, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc3};
    int(*function)()=(int(*)())VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof(data), MEM_COMMIT,  PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    memcpy(function, data, sizeof(data));
    cout << function();
    VirtualFree(function, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    return 0;
}
```

Можно создавать функцию прямо из машинного кода. Массив data - это машинный код функции возвращающей число 666. Но ОС не позволит выполнить этот код, поэтому надо выделить область памяти, которую можно выполнять и скопировать туда нашу функцию. То есть функции можно создавать прямо на лету, но такой способ точно не для новичков. Я даже сам не знаю, как таким способом создать хотя бы "Hello, World!". К тому же будет работать только на процессорах архитектуры x86.

Comment: Кроме того, там есть Code DOM и деревья лямбда-выражений.

Comment: >  генерирует код C# и передаёт его компилятору.

В рантайме?

Comment: Генерирует код, сохраняет его в файл, запускает компилятор, передавая ему путь к файлу.

Comment: А как ты передашь какие-либо объекты с исходной программы на сгенерированную? Если нет коммуникации, смысл теряется. Кроме того такое можно сделать с помощью любого языка.

Comment: Передать информацию можно через аргументы вызова, environment, файл, общую память, сокеты (разные) . Наверняка что-нибудь еще перечислить забыл. 

В Вашем случае прямо встроить ее в исходник, который будете компилировать ...

Comment: Да запросто. Загрузить сгенерированную сборку в домен и работать с её типами.

Answer (score -2):

Вопрос слишком глубокий, теоретически - на любом. Макросы - это на этапе компиляции, мета тоже. 
Проще всего на ассемблере. 
А другую программу - тупо в ехе что надо сохраняй и будет счастье.