# Можно ли преобразовать функцию в строку, вырезать кусок кода и вернуть новую функцию?

Tags: javascript, функции

Допустим у меня есть функция, которая модифицирует метод объекта:

```
 var obj = { 
 // some code
 addBefore : function(method,func){
    //some code
    this.before[method].push(func);
    this[method] = function(){
        this.before[method].forEach(function(key){key();});
        this.old[method].call(this);
 }
 }
```

И нужно потом из модифицированного метода  нужновырезать кусок кода. 
Оригинал:

```
 function method(x){
  var result = x*25;
  return result; 
 }
```

Из-за того, что я "модифицирую" функцию искусственно, мне нужна функция, которая переделает этот метод в вид :

```
 function method(x){
  this.before[method].forEach(function(key){key();});
  var result = x*25;
  return result; 
 }
```

А не в вид :

```
 this[method] = function(){
        this.before[method].forEach(function(key){key();});
        this.old[method].call(this);
 }
```

т.е. Просто нужна функция которая принимает на вход другую функцию(f) и строку, удалаяет/заменяет/добавляет строку в функции и возвращает новую функцию(f1).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/42094/Автогенерация-кода/42124#42124

Comment: У вас между первой функцией и второй нет ничего общего. Поясните пожалуйста, зачем вы хотите это делать?

Comment: Изменил описание проблемы.

Comment: Просто запоминать старую функцию я не могу, т.к. там еще есть методы addAfter и addAround, тоже изменяющие метод.

Comment: Стало еще менее понятно. Постарайтесь показать, чего вы хотите добиться. Как вы это будете использовать.

Comment: Я хотел добавить в метод кусок кода, а потом при необходимости вырезать его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться сериализацией, чтобы получить данные в виде строки, а затем воспользоваться функцией [eval()](https://learn.javascript.ru/eval). Например:

```
function Foo(){alert('Hello, world!');}
Foo(); // Hello, world!
var newFoo = Foo.toString().replace('world', 'all');
eval(newFoo);
Foo(); // Hello, all!
```

Так же подобный вопрос с использованием вложенных в объект функций обсуждался в ветке https://stackoverflow.com/a/51123745/3941340.